# Android USB Host Synchronous Bulk Transfer Send then Read

Tags: android, usb, host, synchronous

I'm trying to setup communication over USB on an android Tablet.

I have the communication working Asynchronously. Which is great, and I want that, but I also want to be able to **send a USB command, and wait for the reply** on a different endpoint?

I would like to use `UsbDeviceConnection.BulkTranfer`, since I have it working already with Asynchronously.

I've tried it this way.

```
mConnection.bulkTransfer(mEndpointIntrWrite2, message, message.length, 500);//send
Thread.sleep(500);
mConnection.bulkTransfer(mEndpointIntrRead1, message, message.length, 500);//read
```

I have verified that the data gets sent down, but it doesn't handle the response back.

Is there a way to handle this?

**also**
Since I have it Asynchronously implemented, is there a way to have 2 threads, 1 that sends the message sleeps waits for the reply. thread 2 handles the reply and triggers Thread 1 to wake up.

Comment: All transfers, IN or OUT, are host initiated. Have you looked on a USB analyzer to see what the issue is with the IN transaction?

Comment: I haven't yet, I'm still new to the USB Protocol. I'll take a look at it this afternoon. and see if I need to start that transfer.

Comment: By making the bulkTransfer call it should send the proper IN request on the bus, but the device needs to respond to it. Also, just double check that your endpoint address is valid for mEndpointIntrRead1